# Сколько придаточных в сложноподчинённом предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Сколько придаточных и какая часть главная в предложении:

> Этот мост, который, (?) хотя и был сделан из дерева, стоял здесь так долго, будто был всегда.

На сайте «Решу ЕГЭ» объяснено так:
три придаточных: 1) который стоял здесь так давно, 2) хотя и был сделан из дерева, 3) будто был всегда. Значит, главная часть: этот мост.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд, существует только один формально правильный способ толкования данного предложения (хотя маловероятно, что автор действительно это имел в виду)

Реплика за кадром: "Этот мост стоял здесь 10 лет".

**Этот мост**, который, хотя и был сделан из дерева, стоял здесь ТАК долго (а именно, 10 лет, как было сказано за кадром), — **будто был всегда.**

Главное: Этот мост будто был всегда.
Придаточное (мост какой?):  который стоял здесь так долго (10 лет).
Придаточное (стоял так долго несмотря на что?): хотя и был сделан из дерева.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь действительно три придаточных предложения:

1) «мост ***(какой?)***, который <...> стоял здесь так долго...» — придаточное определительное, присоединенное с помощью относительного местоимения *который*, выполняющего роль союза, к главному предложению «этот мост»;

2) «стоял здесь так долго ***(несмотря на что?)***, хотя и был сделан из дерева» — придаточное уступки с союзом *хотя*, присоединенное к главному «стоял здесь так долго»;

3) «стоял здесь так долго ***(как долго?)***, будто был всегда» — придаточное времени, присоединенное с помощью союза *будто* к главному «стоял здесь так долго».

Таким образом, придаточные относятся к разным предложениям, поэтому говорить о каком-то одном главном, на мой взгляд, не вполне корректно.

Comment: Значит, главная часть предложения "этот мост"? Без сказуемого. Это назывное предложение или неполное?

Comment: @Lara главных здесь несколько, см. ответ. «Этот мост» — назывное предложение, верно.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что у **этого предложения некорректная грамматика**, его содержание можно представить в таких вариантах:

1) **Этот мост**, хотя (он) и был сделан из дерева, **стоял здесь так долго**, будто был всегда.

2) **Этот мост**, который был сделан из дерева, **стоял здесь так долго**, будто был всегда.

3) **Это   мост**, который хотя и был сделан из дерева, (но) стоял здесь так долго, будто был всегда.   Это – подлежащее, мост – сказуемое. Союз ХОТЯ...НО соединяет однородные сказуемые в придаточном определительном предложении.

Во всех случаях два придаточных.

**Вряд ли "этот мост" является назывным предложением** в такой  сложной конструкции.

Comment: А как Вы оцениваете следующую версию: главное предложение

Comment: ..так долго, будто был здесь всегда. Это придаточное степени и сравнения, то есть единая конструкция, разделять нельзя. Как вариант, в задании всё-таки пропустили букву (опечатка), тогда: "Это мост, который, хотя и был сделан из дерева, стоял здесь так долго, будто был всегда". Хотя предложение кажется немного неестественным, трудно "додумать" для него подходящий текст. Наверное, учебный пример повышенной сложности

Answer (score 1):

> *Этот мост, который, (?) хотя и был сделан из дерева, стоял здесь так
>   долго, будто был всегда.*
>
> Сколько придаточных и какая часть главная в предложении?

Более-менее нормально читаться приведённое в вопросе предложение будет, если выкинуть из него одну букву (*это**т** -> это*):

***Это мост, который, хотя и был сделан из дерева, стоял здесь так долго, будто был всегда.***

Здесь главное: ***Это мост***;

Придаточные:

1. *который стоял здесь так долго;*
2. *хотя и был сделан из дерева;*
3. *будто был всегда.*

Answer (score 0):

А как Вы оцениваете следующую версию: Этот мост будто был всегда  (главная часть); который хотя и был сделан из дерева, (но) стоял здесь так долго (придаточное определительное с однородными сказуемыми). Правда, настораживает указательное наречие "так". 
Вот такие задания предлагают выполнить выпускникам школы.

Comment: _Lara: А как Вы оцениваете следующую версию..._ === Бессмысленно оценивать ЛЮБУЮ версию в ТАК составленном предложении.